# Force Android native keyboard instead custom one

Tags: android, security, kotlin

I was looking is there any possibility to force an app to use the Android native keyboard instead of a custom one (ie Swift keyboard).

Thinking in terms of security this could be an interesting topic in order to prevent loose of information through fake or malicious keyboards.

What do you think, any possibility to do that?

Thanks,
Regards,

Comment: It is not you who can choose which keyboard the users should use. However, if you want it only for your app - you can develop your own *keyboard* which will be just a pannel with buttons, which will add this or that character to the focused EditText.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK there is no possibility of enforcing the default keyboard, I've also found nothing about this in the [OWASP Mobile Security Testing Guide](https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-mstg/).

I fear this is the reason why some applications provide their own custom keyboard for PIN/Code entry.

Another hint: if you use sensitive text fields you should at least disable auto-correct (and automatic learning of new words) for this field. Otherwise the password could be found in the autocorrect database (which was shared between users on older android versions).